# Should brackets be placed around an exponentiated factorial?

Tags: notation

For example, one can derive an approximation of $\pi$ from Stirling's approximation with one additional term as
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{72n(n!)^2}{n^{2n} e^{-2n} (12n+1)^2}
$$

but is it correct to write

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{72n(n!^2)}{n^{2n} e^{-2n} (12n+1)^2}?
$$

Is the ! sufficient to separate the factoriand (if that's the word) from the exponent? I've seen both used in various places.

Comment: I changed \frac{72n(n!)^2}{{n^{2n}} {e^{-2n}}{(12n+1)^2}} to \frac{72n(n!)^2}{n^{2n} e^{-2n} (12n+1)^2}.  The former is hard to read and edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a matter of preference.  I think either one is fine since $!^2$ has no meaning on its own, so the only way to interpret $n!^2$ is as $(n!)^2$.  That being said, I think $(n!)^2$ looks a bit nicer.

Comment: Following from that, are the brackets even necessary after 72n in my formula?

Comment: I would say yes, since $n n!$ could be interpreted as $n(n!)$ or $(nn)!$.  Whenever there's a chance for ambiguity, you should use parentheses.

Comment: This makes me think that the old notation for factorial (a long division sign rotated 180 degrees, with a line under all the affected math and a horizontal line at the right) should be brought back now that we have modern typesetting. Also, that's precisely why I used all the brackets in the two formulas above, which Michael Hardy edited.